# How to get products in a category with subcategories?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm making and eCommerce website and I'm facing a problem in product listings when i want to SELECT products in category with sub categories my simplified database structure is 
**Categories_tbl**

[image]

**Products_tbl**

[image]

So Basically i want to when i query products in Groceries to return all products in table shown above and when i query products in Packed Food to return all of them except Rice

is there a way to do it with a single query, i know that it can be done in php with tons of queries especially if there are alot of subcategories (which is the case)

Comment: MySQL has basically no support for hierarchical or recursive queries.  You can represent the data differently -- showing the full path -- or use a different database.

Comment: Excuse me being low-informed , What do you mean by showing the full path, does is mean using parent_id to by multiple ids like for tuna to be 0/1/2 ? if that is the case then how to do it with a single query to assist performance ?

Comment: Here is a good discussion:  http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/.

Comment: Thanks, However i read that already and i didn't understand, do you have any other ideas for my case ? or maybe if you can a little explain how to implement that technique even if it involves changing my database  structure

Comment: This question regularly comes up on SO, there are dozens of previous questions you could have looked up. I included the one I like the most out of them as the duplicate link.

Comment: Thank you , I searched and didn't find a straightforward answer like the one you marked as duplicate @Shadow